# dbm instance is false

Tags: python, dbm

In python 2.6.5, an instance of dbm does not have a __nonzero__ or a __len__ method, so why does it evaluate false as a boolean?

```
>>> a = dbm.open( 'foo', 'c' )
>>> if a: print 'true'
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) one of the types of values that is considered false is

> any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.

Since a `dbm` object is a mapping and a new instance is empty, it is therefore false.